# How to increment ProgressBar percentage on thread status?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have created a software that allow me to synchronize a large amount of data on an online database. Now I have the form called `Synchronization`, when the user open this form, in the `Form Load event` I execute a function called `SyncData`. This function working well but I want show the percentage progress on the `ProgressBar` available on the `Synchronization` form. I call the function like this:

```
Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf SyncData)
thread.Start()
```

the code above is located in `Form Load Event` as I explained. Essentially my `SyncData` function have a loop that iterate through all records available on local db and perform the insert / update / remove statement. How I can achieve on a similar thing?

Comment: Why not just use a BackgroundWorker for that?

Comment: BackGround worker automatically increase the progress bar?

Comment: It has a [ProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: But how I can join my function to this BackGroundWorker and increase the progress bar?

Comment: You run your thread code in the DoWork method of the BackgroundWorker.  Don't be afraid to try a little research on that component.

Comment: Hahaha @LarsTech, sure man, sorry for this, sometimes I ask too many questions. I'll check on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
Dim syncThread As New Thread(AddressOf SyncData)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    syncThread.IsBackground = True
    syncThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SyncData()

    Dim dt As DataTable ' = your data you are using
    invokeme(Sub() ProgressBar1.Maximum = dt.Rows.Count)

    For Each row In dt.Rows
        'do your syncing

        invokeme(Sub() ProgressBar1.Increment(1))
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub invokeme(ByVal iaction As Action)
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(iaction)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

So you just need the invokeme sub and then set the progressbar's max to the number of rows and after each row is done use this line:

invokeme(Sub() ProgressBar1.Increment(1))

Comment: Where I should pass my SyncData function?

Comment: I changed the code, I'm not a pro. But it did work when I tried it.

Comment: @myekem the only problem's that SyncData function is in another class, so how I can call invokeme from SyncData function that's located in another class?

Comment: change it to public.. I have one setup just like that in my app I made and it works. Don't forget to mark it solved because I did solve the original problem.